# MySQL query fails silently in php

Tags: php, mysql, web

This is my PHP code written for website. When I executed this, the query doesn't execute and doesn't show any error. I also checked data types of values that are to be inserted.
The database username and password and all credentials are correct. What could be the problem?

```
   <?php 
    $password ='abcdef';



      $host="localhost"; // Host name 
      $username="futureti_dsatya"; // Mysql username 
      $password="D2e3e4v1i"; // Mysql password 
      $db_name="futureti_db"; // Database name 
      $tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

     // Connect to server and select databse.
     $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$db_name); 
     if(!$con)
     {
      die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
     }

    else
    {
     $res = mysqli_query($con,"insert into users values(55555623,'saran1','satya_saran',$password)");


    if($res){
       print("i am ok");
    }
    else{
    print("bad");
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: `$password` to `'$password'` and since u are learning why not start using PDO with prepared statements

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty mysqli is a perfectly cromulent alternative to PDO, although [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is a fine idea.

Comment: wrap `$password` in quotes `(55555623,'saran1','satya_saran','$password')` and change `mysql_error());` to `mysqli_error());` those two functions don't mix. As already stated, you're using `$password` twice; change one of the variables to something else.

Comment: @MackieeE why did you make this as a community wiki?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi Fred, I didn't realise I had done, sorry :S how to undo?

Comment: Just do a rollback @MackieeE it's no biggie, but it shouldn't be a wiki since it is the OP's question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just attempted and no change :/ I'll flag it, apologies.

Comment: No need to flag it @MackieeE I will rollback.

Comment: I spoke too soon, it can't be done lol @MackieeE oh well. Yea, you can flag it.

Comment: [**See the answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69031/) on the subject. @MackieeE I just found that in Google.

Comment: @MackieeE You owe me an upvote! hahahaha I'm just kidding lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `$pass` in quotes `(55555623,'saran1','satya_saran','$pass')` as shown below with an explanation about "`$password`", and change `mysql_error());` to `mysqli_error());` those two functions don't mix and that is why you did not get the proper error messages to show up.

As already stated, you're using `$password` twice; change one of the variables to something else.

What you're presently doing is overwriting your `$password` variable.

I am assuming you want to enter `abcdef` into your DB. If so, then do this instead:

```
<?php 
   $pass ='abcdef';
   $host = "localhost"; // Host name 
   $username = "futureti_dsatya"; // Mysql username 
   $password = "D2e3e4v1i"; // Mysql password 
   $db_name = "futureti_db"; // Database name 
   $tbl_name = "users"; // Table name 

   // Connect to server and select databse.
   $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password,$db_name); 

  if ( !$con ) {
       die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error());

  } else {

      $res = mysqli_query($con, "insert into users values (55555623,'saran1','satya_saran','$pass' )");
      if( $res ) {
         print("i am ok");
      } else {
         print("bad");
      }
  }
?>
```

Also, inserting data into a table without telling it which columns to use is not a recommended method.

Use something to the effect of:

```
($con, "insert into users (column1, column2, column3, column4) values (55555623,'saran1','satya_saran','$pass' )
```

Sidenote: If the column for your first value isn't an `(int)` you will need to wrap that in quotes as well.

Also, if your first column is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you will need to remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` from the column's type.

Comment: I don't know how this landed up in community wiki, I guess that Espresso hasn't kicked in yet. Oh well, no biggie.

Comment: Ah now I know why; the question was edited "as" a community wiki. *Will you lookah dat.*

Comment: yeah, okay now. I know its a silly question but I am not able to check for the variables instead looking for connection and other things that's why I am confused of the query execution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? @user3481084 I'm not following.

Comment: its now working, as you said i used same name for two variables. I didn't recognized that and checking for other issues in my php script.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @user3481084

Comment: thanks Mr. Fred for answering my such silly question with your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

you dont get any error because you are making using mysql. not mysqli.

your code is wroking just wrap password . i guess the connection is not connecting.

replace this:

```
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
```

to

```
    die('Could not connect: '. mysqli_error());  //to see the error
```